# Initialize a toggle button as off

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to start a toggle button using the new Unity interface but I want it to start as Off or unchecked.

I created the button:´

```
public Toggle toggleBool1;
```

and dragged the toggle button created in the scene into this toggleBool1 slot in the inspector it works fine, but I can't make it to start as off.

Do you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the `Toggle.isOn` property to check/uncheck the toggle in code.  For example, you can set `isOn` to `false` in the `Start()` method of the script you have dragged the `Toggle` onto to make the `Toggle` start off unchecked.

```
public Toggle toggleBool1;

void Start ()
{
    toggleBool1.isOn = false;
}
```

Comment: Can't I just make toggleBool1 = false;  ??

Comment: I want to start as Off but I need this toggleBool1.isOn to work normally

Comment: so I can check when it is turned ON

Comment: James Hogle is correct. That's how to do it. Try it before making further comments.

Comment: You can't say toggleBool1 = false because toggleBool1 is a Toggle control, not a boolean.  toggleBool1.isOn will still work normally, as it will always return whether or not the toggle control is checked.